# MS ACCESS - How to search for a value in a combobox on two columns

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a form with a combobox that has 2 columns.
When i type something in, i want the combo search in both 2 columns for a match not just in the first one..

I really don't have an idea how to achieve that.
I thought it can work in VBA with `ItemData` or `RowSource` properties on `Change` event..

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data as text table.

Answer (score 0):

Have combobox RowSource be a UNION query that lists values of both fields as one column, like:

```
SELECT ID, field1 AS Data FROM table
UNION SELECT ID, field2 FROM table;
```

Comment: this doesn't help my goal which is searching on both columns when i type something in the combobox, your example still search in the first column.

Comment: Yes, but it wall match on data that is stored in either field. Then reference combobox under both fields with OR operator for criteria.

Comment: what you exactly mean with: reference combobox under both fields with OR operator for criteria?

Comment: Something like: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field1 = combobox OR field2=combobox;`